Getting wrong filename, cName, cValue from xml extracted using linq
I have a project that reads xml of expected build results for each build area, and compares against build logs to see if the build passed.  The xml does not look like it's reading correctly. Does anyone know what's wrong with the linq that makes the xml retrieved incorrect?
I've been looking at these examples:
linq
linq
However, it's getting the wrong cName and cValue when I print it to check it before I use it. Also, it's always giving filename1.cs:
wrong:
19:00
build_machine='mach31', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\R\filename1.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach31', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\R\filename1.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach31', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\R\filename1.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename4.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename4.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename4.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename4.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename4.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename4.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename4.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename4.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename4.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinISProjectVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename4.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'

should be:
19:00
build_machine='mach31', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\R\filename1.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach31', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\R\filename2.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach31', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\R\filename3.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename4.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename5.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename6.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\D\filename7.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\K\filename8.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\K\filename9.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\K\filename11.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename22.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename33.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinISProjectVersionStats', condition name='ProductName', condition value = 'P1', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'

...
So far I have this code:
void ReadXml()
{
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    string newPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(path, @"..\.."));
    string finalPathXml = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(newPath, @"BuildVerificationBuildAttributes.xml"));

    //linq 
    XDocument xmlDoc1 = XDocument.Load(finalPathXml);
    XElement buildVerificationElement = xmlDoc1.Element("BuildVerification");
    IEnumerable<XElement> buildElements = buildVerificationElement.Elements("build");
    IEnumerable<XElement> buildMachines = buildElements.Elements("BuildMachine");

    //get just the times from the xml
    var codeFreezeTime = xmlDoc1.Descendants("codeFreezeTime").First()?.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(codeFreezeTime);

    IEnumerable<XElement> processes = buildMachines.Elements("Process");
    IEnumerable<XElement> processNames = processes.Elements("ProcessName");
    IEnumerable<XElement> conditions = processNames.Elements("Conditions");
    var found = xmlDoc1.XPathEvaluate("/BuildVerification/build/BuildMachine/Process/ProcessName/Conditions") as IEnumerable<object>;

    var results =
        xmlDoc1.Descendants("build")
        .SelectMany(x => x.Descendants("Process")
        .SelectMany(y => y.Descendants("SuccessCriteria")
        .Select(z => new
        {
            buildMach = (string)x.Element("BuildMachine"),
            p1 = (string)y.Element("ProcessName"),
            cName = (string)x.Descendants("Condition").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("name"),
            cValue = (string)x.Descendants("Condition").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("value"),
            f1 = (string)z.Element("field"),
            c1 = (string)z.Element("comparison"),
            v1 = (string)z.Element("value")
        }))).ToList();
    foreach (var cur in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("build_machine='{0}', process_name='{1}', condition name='{2}', condition value = '{3}', field='{4}', comparison='{5}', value='{6}'",
            cur.buildMach, cur.p1, cur.cName, cur.cValue, cur.f1, cur.c1, cur.v1);

        //get log data out to compare
        if((cur.buildMach == "mach46") && (cur.p1 == "SpinISProjectVersionStats"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("here"); //*at this point I see cur.cName=VersionFile which is wrong
        }
        //ParseLogFile(codeFreezeTime/*, versionChangeTime*/, cur.buildMach, cur.p1, cur.cName, cur.cValue, cur.f1, cur.c1, cur.v1);
    }

}

This is what my xml looks like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BuildVerification>
   <codeFreezeTime>19:00</codeFreezeTime>
   <build>
       <BuildMachine>mach31</BuildMachine>
        <Process>
            <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <Conditions>
                    <Condition
                        name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\R\filename1.cs">
                        <SuccessCriteria>
                            <field>Status</field>
                            <comparison>equal</comparison> <!--can't use >= here -->
                            <value>Success</value>
                        </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                </Conditions>
        </Process>
        <Process>
            <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <Conditions>
                    <Condition
                        name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\R\filename2.cs">
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                <value>Success</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                </Conditions>
        </Process>
        <Process>
            <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <Conditions>
                    <Condition
                        name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\R\filename3.h">
                        <SuccessCriteria>
                        <field>Status</field>
                        <comparison>equal</comparison>
                        <value>Success</value>

                        </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                </Conditions>
        </Process>

    </build>
    
    
    <build>
    <BuildMachine>mach46</BuildMachine>
        <Process>
            <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <Conditions>
                    <Condition
                        name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename4.cs">
                        <SuccessCriteria>
                            <field>Status</field>
                            <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                            <value>Success</value>
                        </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                </Conditions>
        </Process>
        <Process>
            <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <Conditions>
                    <Condition
                        name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\fiename5.h">
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                <value>Success</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                </Conditions>
        </Process>
        <Process>
            <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <Conditions>
                    <Condition
                        name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename6.cs">

                        <SuccessCriteria>
                        <field>Status</field>
                        <comparison>equal</comparison>
                        <value>Success</value>

                        </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                </Conditions>
        </Process>
        
        <Process>
            <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <Conditions>
                    <Condition
                        name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\D\filename7.cs">
                        <SuccessCriteria>
                            <field>Status</field>
                            <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                            <value>Success</value>
                        </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                </Conditions>
        </Process>
        <Process>
            <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <Conditions>
                    <Condition
                        name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\K\filename8.cs">

                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                <value>Success</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                </Conditions>
        </Process>
        <Process>
            <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <Conditions>
                    <Condition
                        name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\K\filename9.h">

                        <SuccessCriteria>
                        <field>Status</field>
                        <comparison>equal</comparison>
                        <value>Success</value>

                        </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                </Conditions>
        </Process>
        
                    
        <Process>
            <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <Conditions>
                    <Condition
                        name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\K\filename11.cs">
                        <SuccessCriteria>
                            <field>Status</field>
                            <comparison>equal</comparison> <!--can't use >= here -->
                            <value>Success</value>
                        </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                </Conditions>
        </Process>
        <Process>
            <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <Conditions>
                    <Condition
                        name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename22.cs">

                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                <value>Success</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                </Conditions>
        </Process>
        <Process>
            <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <Conditions>
                    <Condition
                        name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename33.cs">

                        <SuccessCriteria>
                            <field>Status</field>
                            <comparison>equal</comparison>
                            <value>Success</value>

                        </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                </Conditions>
        </Process>
        
        
        <Process>
            <ProcessName>SpinISProjectVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <Conditions>
                    <Condition
                        name='ProductName' value="P1">

                        <SuccessCriteria>
                            <field>Status</field>
                            <comparison>equal</comparison>
                            <value>Success</value>

                        </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                </Conditions>
        </Process>
        <Process>
            <ProcessName>SpinISProjectVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <Conditions>
                    <Condition
                        name='ProductName' value="P2">

                        <SuccessCriteria>
                            <field>Status</field>
                            <comparison>equal</comparison>
                            <value>Success</value>

                        </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                </Conditions>
        </Process>
        <Process>
            <ProcessName>SpinISProjectVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <Conditions>
                    <Condition
                        name='ProductName' value="P3">

                        <SuccessCriteria>
                            <field>Status</field>
                            <comparison>equal</comparison>
                            <value>Success</value>

                        </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                </Conditions>
        </Process>
        <Process>
            <ProcessName>GetSWStats</ProcessName>
                <Conditions>
                    <Condition
                        name='DestinationPath' value="D:\Builds\Retail\nightly">

                        <SuccessCriteria>
                            <field>UpdateRequired</field>
                            <comparison>equal</comparison>
                            <value>YES</value>

                        </SuccessCriteria>
    
                    </Condition>
                    <Condition
                        name='DestinationPath' value="D:\Builds\Retail\nightly">

                        <SuccessCriteria>
                            <field>Status</field>
                            <comparison>equal</comparison>
                            <value>Successful</value>

                        </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                </Conditions>
        </Process>
        
        <Process>
            <ProcessName>ParseISLogStats</ProcessName>
                <Conditions>
                    <Condition
                        name='BuildProject' value="RetailInstallerBuild">
                        <SuccessCriteria>
                            <field>Projects</field>
                            <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                            <value>33</value>
                        </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                    <Condition
                        name='BuildProject' value="RetailInstallerBuild">
                        <SuccessCriteria>
                            <field>Projects</field>
                            <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                            <value>8</value>
                        </SuccessCriteria>
                        <SuccessCriteria>
                            <field>Status</field>
                            <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                            <value>Success</value>
                        </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                </Conditions>
        </Process>
        <Process>
            <ProcessName>UpdateBuildArea-Stats</ProcessName>
                <Conditions>
                    <Condition
                        name='DestPath' value="\\mach62\Builds\nightly">

                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Dir</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                <value>Retail</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                    <Condition
                        name='DestPath' value="\\mach62\Builds\nightly">

                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>eSecs</field>
                                <comparison>greaterThan</comparison>
                                <value>0</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                    </Condition>
                </Conditions>
        </Process>
    </build>
</BuildVerification>


It looks like you are getting the first Condition Name/Value for the containing build (variable x in your LINQ expression). I believe you need to get the first for the containing Process (variable y in your LINQ).  Even better might be to add a .SelectMany(process => x.Descendants("Condition")) to your LINQ so that you can access the condition object directly in the later .Select(...).

Changing your variables to more meaningful names instead of x, y and z would help with readability. Names like build, process, condition, and successCriteria would be better, or even b, p, c, and sc, if you prefer short names (local to the LINQ expression).

It looks like you are getting the first Condition Name/Value for the containing build element (variable x in your LINQ expression). I believe you need to get the first for the containing Process element (variable y in your LINQ). Even better might be to add a .SelectMany(process => x.Descendants("Condition") ... ) to your LINQ so that you can access the condition element directly in the later .Select(...).
Changing your variables to more meaningful names in place of x, y and z would help with readability. Names like build, process, condition, and successCriteria would be better, or even b, p, c, and sc, if you prefer short mnemonic names (when used local to the LINQ expression).
Try:
    var results =
        xmlDoc1.Descendants("build")
        .SelectMany(b => b.Descendants("Process")
        .SelectMany(p => p.Descendants("Condition")  // Added
        .SelectMany(c => c.Descendants("SuccessCriteria")
        .Select(sc => new
            {
                buildMach = (string)b.Element("BuildMachine"),
                p1 = (string)p.Element("ProcessName"),
                cName = (string)c.Attribute("name"),   // Simplified access
                cValue = (string)c.Attribute("value"), // Simplified access
                f1 = (string)sc.Element("field"),
                c1 = (string)sc.Element("comparison"),
                v1 = (string)sc.Element("value")
            }
        ))))
        .ToList();


I have repeating build and process and success criteria sections in the xml.

You also have multiple Condition elements per Process in some cases. (See "ParseISLogStats" in the sample data.) The above should handle that.

@T N see also my recent post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78343545/how-check-linq-xml-against-file-when-multiple-conditions/78344227#78344227

Starting from the SuccessCriteria nodes, do an upwards navigation via the Parent property to get the values for cNameand cValue.
var results =
    xmlDoc1.Descendants("build")
    .SelectMany(x => x.Descendants("Process")
    .SelectMany(y => y.Descendants("SuccessCriteria")
    .Select(z => new
    {
        cName = (string)z.Parent.Attribute("name"),
        cValue = (string)z.Parent.Attribute("value")
        
        // Remaining properties
        
    }))).ToList();


