How check linq/xml against file when multiple conditions?
I have a project that reads xml of expected build results for each build area, and compares against build logs to see if the build passed.  Right now, the linq is showing each condition in a separate line of results, but (since I'm looping thru each linq result line to check for success) I need to be able to check both conditions (if there are two) at the same time, not different times. Otherwise I could be checking the wrong line of the log file. Note that sometimes there are two success criteria but not always.  It's just the two conditions I need to check at once.
My question is, how do check both conditions at once?  For example, the table I put in xml looks like this for some of the log, ParseISLogStats (so I need to check BuildProject and BaseBuildArea are correct together in the log because they are different columns, but the success criteria is only one for those two conditions):
ParseISLogStats    BuildProject=DInstallerBuild   BaseBuildArea=D:\R\K\v2.1\nightly   Status=Success
ParseISLogStats    BuildProject=KInstallerBuild   BaseBuildArea=D:\R\K\v2.1\nightly   Status=Success
ParseISLogStats    BuildProject=IInstallerBuild   BaseBuildArea=D:\R\K\v2.1\nightly   Status=Success

and it's log file I'm checking against looks like this:
StartTime           EndTime             Day Elapsed     sec Status  BuildProj       Desc  Projects  FailedProj  Errors  Warnings  FailedProjList  BaseBuildArea  LogFile  AdditionalInfo
04/16/24 21:57:31   04/16/24 22:02:46   Tue 00:05:15    315 Success DInstallerBuild K v2.1 nightly  16  0   0   20      D:\R_Builds\K\v2.1\nightly  X:\D\Build\Installers\DInstallerBuild.log   
04/16/24 22:06:53   04/16/24 22:18:20   Tue 00:11:27    687 Success KInstallerBuild K v2.1 nightly  9   0   0   19      D:\R_Builds\K\v2.1\nightly  X:\K\Build\Installers\KInstallerBuild.log   
04/16/24 22:26:43   04/16/24 22:29:32   Tue 00:02:49    169 Success KInstallerBuild K v2.1 nightly  2   0   0   5       D:\R_Builds\K\v2.1\nightly  X:\K\Build\Installers\KInstallerBuild.log   
04/17/24 00:19:00   04/17/24 00:24:00   Wed 00:05:00    300 Success Incremental_v2.1    v2.1 Incremental Installer Builds   5   0   0   8       D:\R_Builds\K\v2.1\nightly  I:\Logs\IncrementalInstallBuildLog_v2.1.txt

I've been looking at these examples:
linq
linq
The linq in my code is retrieving what looks like this:
19:00
build_machine='mach31', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\R\filename1.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach31', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\R\filename2.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach31', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\R\filename3.h', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename4.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\fiename5.h', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename6.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\D\filename7.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\K\filename8.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\K\filename9.h', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\K\filename11.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename22.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinFileVersionStats', condition name='VersionFile', condition value = '\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename33.cs', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinISProjectVersionStats', condition name='ProductName', condition value = 'P1', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinISProjectVersionStats', condition name='ProductName', condition value = 'P2', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='SpinISProjectVersionStats', condition name='ProductName', condition value = 'P3', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='GetSWStats', condition name='DestinationPath', condition value = 'D:\Builds\Retail\nightly', field='UpdateRequired', comparison='equal', value='YES'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='GetSWStats', condition name='DestinationPath', condition value = 'D:\Builds\Retail\nightly', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Successful'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='ParseISLogStats', condition name='BuildProject', condition value = 'RetailInstallerBuild', field='Projects', comparison='equal', value='33'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='ParseISLogStats', condition name='BuildProject', condition value = 'RetailInstallerBuild', field='Projects', comparison='equal', value='8'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='ParseISLogStats', condition name='BuildProject', condition value = 'RetailInstallerBuild', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='ParseISLogStats', condition name='BuildProject', condition value = 'DInstallerBuild', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='ParseISLogStats', condition name='BaseBuildArea', condition value = 'D:\R_Builds\K\v2.1\nightly', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='ParseISLogStats', condition name='BuildProject', condition value = 'KInstallerBuild', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='ParseISLogStats', condition name='BaseBuildArea', condition value = 'D:\R_Builds\K\v2.1\nightly', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='ParseISLogStats', condition name='BuildProject', condition value = 'KInstallerBuild', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='ParseISLogStats', condition name='BaseBuildArea', condition value = 'D:\R_Builds\K\v2.1\nightly', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='ParseISLogStats', condition name='BuildProject', condition value = 'Incremental_v2.1', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='ParseISLogStats', condition name='BaseBuildArea', condition value = 'D:\RP_Builds\KPEX\v24.1\nightly', field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='UpdateBuildArea-Stats', condition name='DestPath', condition value = '\\mach62\Builds\nightly', field='Dir', comparison='equal', value='Retail'
build_machine='mach46', process_name='UpdateBuildArea-Stats', condition name='DestPath', condition value = '\\mach62\Builds\nightly', field='eSecs', comparison='greaterThan', value='0'

So far I have this code:
        void ReadXml()
    {
        int i_results = 0; //0 is successful for all; if it increases we have failed in one
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string newPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(path, @"..\.."));
        string finalPathXml = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(newPath, @"BuildVerificationBuildAttributes_t.xml"));

        //linq 
        XDocument xmlDoc1 = XDocument.Load(finalPathXml);
        XElement buildVerificationElement = xmlDoc1.Element("BuildVerification");
        IEnumerable<XElement> buildElements = buildVerificationElement.Elements("build");
        IEnumerable<XElement> buildMachines = buildElements.Elements("BuildMachine");

        //get just the times from the xml
        var codeFreezeTime = xmlDoc1.Descendants("codeFreezeTime").First()?.Value;
        Console.WriteLine(codeFreezeTime);

        IEnumerable<XElement> processes = buildMachines.Elements("Process");
        IEnumerable<XElement> processNames = processes.Elements("ProcessName");
        IEnumerable<XElement> conditions = processNames.Elements("Conditions");
        var found = xmlDoc1.XPathEvaluate("/BuildVerification/build/BuildMachine/Process/ProcessName/Conditions") as IEnumerable<object>;

        var results =
            xmlDoc1.Descendants("build")
            .SelectMany(b => b.Descendants("Process")
            .SelectMany(p => p.Descendants("Condition")
            .SelectMany(c =>c.Descendants("SuccessCriteria")
            .Select(sc => new
            {
                buildMach = (string)b.Element("BuildMachine"),
                p1 = (string)p.Element("ProcessName"),
                startTimeHeader = (string)p.Element("startTimeHeader"),
                cName = (string)c.Attribute("name"),
                cValue = (string)c.Attribute("value"),
                f1 = (string)sc.Element("field"),
                c1 = (string)sc.Element("comparison"),
                v1 = (string)sc.Element("value")
            })))).ToList();
        foreach (var cur in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("build_machine='{0}', process_name='{1}', condition name='{2}', condition value = '{3}', field='{4}', comparison='{5}', value='{6}'",
                cur.buildMach, cur.p1, cur.cName, cur.cValue, cur.f1, cur.c1, cur.v1);

            
            i_results += ParseLogFile(codeFreezeTime, cur.startTimeHeader, cur.buildMach, cur.p1, cur.cName, cur.cValue, cur.f1, cur.c1, cur.v1);
        }

        if(i_results > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Build has failed this many times:{0} ", i_results);
    }

The code that gets the info out of the linq is like this, but it's long but I'm only showing the first part:
int ParseLogFile(string codeFreezeTime, string startTimeHeader, string serverName, string logName, string cName, string cValue, string field1, string comparison1, string val)
{
    //bool b_results = false; //failed

    bool b_foundResultWhenExpected = false;
    int i_results = 0; //add 1 for each fail
    //path to file to read and parse
    string serverPath = @"\\\\" + serverName;
    string logNameFull = logName + ".txt";
    string partialPath = "";

    string combinedPath2 = partialPath + logNameFull;
    Uri serverUri = new Uri(serverPath + combinedPath2);
    string finalPath = serverUri.LocalPath;

    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    string s_today = today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1); //code freeze day is day before run check
    DateTime dayBeforeYesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2); //for SpinFile logs we use any time after previous code freeze
    string yesterdayDate = (yesterday).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    string dayBeforeYesterdayDate = (dayBeforeYesterday).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    string yesterdayDateWithTime = yesterdayDate + " " + codeFreezeTime;
    string dayBeforeYesterdayDateWithTime = dayBeforeYesterdayDate + " " + codeFreezeTime;
    CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    DateTime yesterdayDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(yesterdayDateWithTime, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", provider);
    DateTime DayBeforeYesterdayDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dayBeforeYesterdayDateWithTime, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", provider);

    // Read file content into a DataTable using delimiters
    DataTable dataTable = ReadDataTable(finalPath);

    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch((row[startTimeHeader]).ToString(), @"^\d+")) //date starts with number..filter out rows that have general logging instead of dated table entries
        {

                string tmpStartDT = ((row[startTimeHeader]).ToString()).Trim(); //in case extra spaces for date string

                tmpStartDT = tmpStartDT.Replace("  ", " "); //take care of datetime that have two spaces between date and time, which is an error
                                                            //using H and not HH because military time (capital H), and this handles 0:01 and 05:01 and 14:01 (one H)
                if (((logName.Contains("Spin")) && (startDate > DayBeforeYesterdayDateTime)) || (startDate > yesterdayDateTime))
                {
                   if (((string)row[cName]).Replace("\\", "") == (cValue).Replace("\\", "")) //put this after date check
                   {
                     float left = 0, right = 0;
                     string mostRecentComparison = row[field1].ToString();
                     switch (comparison1)
                     {
                        case "equal":
                                if (mostRecentComparison == val) //pass/success
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(serverName + " " + logName + " " + cName + " " + cValue + " " + field1 + " " + comparison1 + " " + mostRecentComparison + " Perfect!");
                                }
                                else if (logName == "GetSWStats")
                                {
                                    if (val == "UpToDate")
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine(serverName + " " + logName + " " + cName + " " + cValue + " " + field1 + " " + comparison1 + " " + mostRecentComparison + "Which is ok");

                                    }
                                }
                                else //fail
                                {   //check for retries
                                    if (!peekAheadToSeeIfSuccessWhenInFailure(dataTable, (debug_i - 1), cValue, cName, field1, comparison1, val)) //it never retries successfully
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine(serverName + " " + logName + " " + cName + " " + cValue + " " + field1 + " " + mostRecentComparison + " " + " does not " + comparison1 + " " + val + " Found: " + mostRecentComparison + " Error! *****"); //show value of row, not xml val
                                        i_results++;
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            ...
                  }//valid time
            }//foreach

} //ParseLogFile

This is what my xml looks like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BuildVerification>
    <codeFreezeTime>19:00</codeFreezeTime>
    <build>
        <BuildMachine>mach31</BuildMachine>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\R\filename1.cs">
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                                <value>Success</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\R\filename2.cs">
                                <SuccessCriteria>
                                    <field>Status</field>
                                    <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                    <value>Success</value>

                                </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\R\filename3.h">
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                            <field>Status</field>
                            <comparison>equal</comparison>
                            <value>Success</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>

        </build>
        
        
        <build>
        <BuildMachine>mach46</BuildMachine>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename4.cs">
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                                <value>Success</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\fiename5.h">
                                <SuccessCriteria>
                                    <field>Status</field>
                                    <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                    <value>Success</value>

                                </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename6.cs">

                            <SuccessCriteria>
                            <field>Status</field>
                            <comparison>equal</comparison>
                            <value>Success</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\D\filename7.cs">
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                                <value>Success</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\K\filename8.cs">

                                <SuccessCriteria>
                                    <field>Status</field>
                                    <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                    <value>Success</value>

                                </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\K\filename9.h">

                            <SuccessCriteria>
                            <field>Status</field>
                            <comparison>equal</comparison>
                            <value>Success</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            
                        
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\K\filename11.cs">
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> <!--can't use >= here -->
                                <value>Success</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename22.cs">

                                <SuccessCriteria>
                                    <field>Status</field>
                                    <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                    <value>Success</value>

                                </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='VersionFile' value="\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\K\filename33.cs">

                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                <value>Success</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            
            
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinISProjectVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='ProductName' value="P1">

                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                <value>Success</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinISProjectVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='ProductName' value="P2">

                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                <value>Success</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinISProjectVersionStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='ProductName' value="P3">

                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                <value>Success</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>GetSWStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='DestinationPath' value="D:\Builds\Retail\nightly">

                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>UpdateRequired</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                <value>YES</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
        
                        </Condition>
                        <Condition
                            name='DestinationPath' value="D:\Builds\Retail\nightly">

                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                <value>Successful</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>ParseISLogStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='BuildProject' value="RetailInstallerBuild">
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Projects</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                                <value>33</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                        <Condition
                            name='BuildProject' value="RetailInstallerBuild">
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Projects</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                                <value>8</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                                <value>Success</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>ParseISLogStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='BuildProject' value="DInstallerBuild">
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                                <value>Success</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                        <Condition
                            name='BaseBuildArea' value="D:\R_Builds\K\v2.1\nightly">
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                                <value>Success</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>ParseISLogStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='BuildProject' value="KInstallerBuild">
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                                <value>Success</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                        <Condition
                            name='BaseBuildArea' value="D:\R_Builds\K\v2.1\nightly">
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                                <value>Success</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                        </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>ParseISLogStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='BuildProject' value="KInstallerBuild">
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                                <value>Success</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                        <Condition
                            name='BaseBuildArea' value="D:\R_Builds\K\v2.1\nightly">
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                                <value>Success</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>ParseISLogStats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='BuildProject' value="Incremental_v2.1">
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                                <value>Success</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                        <Condition
                            name='BaseBuildArea' value="D:\RP_Builds\KPEX\v24.1\nightly">
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                                <value>Success</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>UpdateBuildArea-Stats</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='DestPath' value="\\mach62\Builds\nightly">

                                <SuccessCriteria>
                                    <field>Dir</field>
                                    <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                    <value>Retail</value>

                                </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                        <Condition
                            name='DestPath' value="\\mach62\Builds\nightly">

                                <SuccessCriteria>
                                    <field>eSecs</field>
                                    <comparison>greaterThan</comparison>
                                    <value>0</value>

                                </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
        </build>
    </BuildVerification>


If you are checking multiple conditions, you need to use a GroupBy to combine the multiple items together.

var groups = results.GroupBy(x => new {build_machine = x.build_machine, process_name = x.process_name, name = x.name}).ToList();

Idk how that fits into  var results =
xmlDoc1.Descendants("build")
.SelectMany(b => b.Descendants("Process")
.SelectMany(p => p.Descendants("Condition")
.SelectMany(c =>c.Descendants("SuccessCriteria")
.Select(sc => new
{
buildMach = (string)b.Element("BuildMachine"),
p1 = (string)p.Element("ProcessName"),
startTimeHeader = (string)p.Element("startTimeHeader"),
cName = (string)c.Attribute("name"),
cValue = (string)c.Attribute("value"),
f1 = (string)sc.Element("field"),
c1 = (string)sc.Element("comparison"),
v1 = (string)sc.Element("value")
})))).ToList();

Groupby creates a two dimensional array.  The long dimension is the unique key used in the groupby and the short dimension is an array is the rows that have same key.  So you just need to use a for loop : foreach(var group in groups) { your code };

I'm still not sure how what you show for groups above my last comment fits into my code I have above. Your variables aren't matching mine.  If you mean this (which I have below my var results code), it still has errors.  var groups = results.GroupBy(x => new(buildMach = x.buildMach.p1 = x.p1, nameof = x.cName)).ToList();  Errors: new isn't availabe in c# 7.3, buildMach and nameof doesn't exist in current context, string doesn't have definition for p1

It should be curly brackets with a space after new.  Should be like your select : .Select(sc => new
